# I want to stop and start music in my game project im making

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#main
def Main():
    print("-------------------------------------------")
    choice = input("\n1.See coins \n2.fight \n3.music on \n4.music off \n5.quit \nInput:")
    if choice == "1":
        print("you have: ",character.coins)
        Main()

    elif choice == "2":
        battlestate()

    elif choice == "3":
        music = True;
        music = winsound.PlaySound("311 - Love from Afar.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC | winsound.SND_ALIAS )
        Main()

    elif choice == "4":
        music = False;
        music = winsound.PlaySound("311 - Love from Afar.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC | winsound.SND_ALIAS )
        Main()
        
    elif choice == "5":
        quit()

    else:
        print("i dont understand, please try again!")
        Main()
```

my main method asks the user for inputs as you can see but i want to be able to turn on and off the music. right now if you turn music on it plays the music but if the music isnt playing and you do music off it also starts playing. if music is on and i tell music to turn off it just stops the song and then restarts it from the beginning. i dont think i need to much explanation for this cus the answer is probably pretty obvious but im just missing something with bools.

Comment: Don't call `Main()` recursively from within itself. If you want to loop, then loop. The `music = True/False` code seems to have no purpose. Your `choice == "4"` handler is playing a WAV file (but 4 => music off).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop the music you have to either call `PlaySound()` with no args to stop all sounds or call it with `winsound.SND_PURGE`.

> "If the sound parameter is None, any currently playing waveform sound
> is stopped."

Sauce: https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html